# How to group all records while next record is equal to previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys please help me on how to achieve this result i have below table data

```
AutoID   Quantity
   1        2
   2        2     
   3        2     
   4        7
   5        7
   6        2
   7        2
```

Using `min` and `max`:

```
Select Min(AutoID) as AutoIDMin, Min(AutoID) as AutoIDMax, Quantity  
from table1 GROUP By Quantity
```

My result is:

```
AutoIDMin - AutoIDMax - Quantity
    1           7           2
    4           5           7
```

What i want to achieve is below:

```
AutoIDMin   AutoIDMax   Quantity
    1           3          2
    4           5          7
    6           7          2
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Some description of your logic would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using difference of `ROW_NUMBER`s:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AutoID)
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Quantity ORDER BY AutoID)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    AutoIDMin   = MIN(AutoID),
    AutoIDMax   = MAX(AutoID),
    Quantity 
FROM Cte
GROUP BY grp, Quantity
ORDER BY AutoIDMin
```

*Here is an article by Jeff Moden on grouping islands:
[Group Island of Contiguous Dates](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)*

Comment: Please read the article referenced in the answer.It'll explain the solution better.